# Why does water come out of a bottle in waves?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, everyday-life, water, surface-tension

So imagine you have a bottle of water or any type of liquid (like a bottle of milk that has just been opened)that is completely full or even three quarter of it is full,why does the water or milk come out of the bottle in waves when you pour it in a glass?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't always.

But in general, if you get into a situation where more of it flowing causes less to flow, it's likely to come in waves.

You have an air space. If you tilt the bottle enough that the liquid closes off the air space, then that space gets lower pressure. That slows the liquid flowing. When it slows enough that an air bubble can force its way into the air space, the liquid flow speeds up. Then it slows down again. Wave motion.